# MySQL 8.0 How to Import CSV into mySQL with Large Amount of Columns Using Query/Inline

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

So I figured out the command to import a small CSV file into mySQL, by just making the table columns myself.

However I have a large dataset and I need to make a table that can house 100+ columns, but I find that to be a near impossible task.

```
LOAD DATA INFILE
'C:/ProgramData/MySQL/MySQL Server 8.0/Uploads/Example' 
INTO TABLE exampleTable
#FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
IGNORE 1 LINES;

create table exampleTable(); #this isn't a valid statement
```

How do I generate the table so it automatically takes all 100+ columns from the excel CSV?

Comment: If you've got 100 columns I'd guess that loading it into MySQL in that form will be less than optimal.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create temptable with one TEXT column and one autoincremented ID.
2. Load your CSV into it.
3. Take 1st row (ID = 1). Process it, extract separate columns names.
4. Using dynamic SQL create another temptable with needed structure and all columns of TEXT type.
5. Parse the data rows (starting from line ID = 2) into this table.
6. Process each column separately and try to detect suitable datatype for the data in this column (datetime, date, decimal, integer, etc.).
7. Create static table with needed structure and suitable datatypes.
8. Copy data.